# amazon S3 show default image when image not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I have a query about amazon S3.

I don't know is this fundamental possible or not.

In amazon s3 if image not exist in S3, will throw 404 error when we hit the cdn url like "https://cdn.storegrasp.com/images/Zwfum1-AYLX9sSK5YZtPLQ-logo.jpg"

so actully I want that amazon s3 will throw me the default image which I was set in amazon s3.

Is this functionality provided by amazon?
If yes, then can you help me step by step how can I achieve this.

Comment: You would typically do this client-side with img onerror, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Comment: You could do it via Amazon S3 static website hosting. See: [Custom Error Document Support](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CustomErrorDocSupport.html)